# Programmatically Inserting Profiling Marks

Tags: .net, visual-studio, profiling, profiler

I'm using the Profiler of Visual Studio 2008 Development Edition.  To perform "targeted profiling," I can manually set profiler filters through "marks" anytime I am attached to my currently-running test code.  But I would like to insert the marks programmatically instead.  I would like to add a call, instruction, or directive to my test code that, when executed, tells the profiler "this is a 'mark' called 'BeginWork'" and "this is a 'mark' called 'EndWork'".

Is there a way to do that?  If not, does Visual Studio 2010 have that ability?

Comment: I think it's worth mentioning that I've found the VS2008 profiler to be explosively terrible at handling non-managed code.  YMMV.  We use AQTime ourself, but I'm not perfectly happy with it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the Profiler API to insert marks programmatically. See the DataCollection.CommentMarkProfile method documentation on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.profiler.datacollection.commentmarkprofile.aspx).

You just need to add a reference to Microsoft.VisualStudio.Profiler.dll from 'Program Files[ x86]\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Team Tools\Performance Tools' to use the managed API.

Your test code could look something like:

```
MarkOperationResult result;
result = DataCollection.CommentMarkProfile(markID1, "BeginWork");
// Validate result...

SomeOperation();

result = DataCollection.CommentMarkProfile(markID2, "EndWork");
// Validate result...
```

Comment: Any idea if there's a Silverlight equivalent?